# Where does 'Microsoft Accessibility Insights' extension (web) store data?

Tags: accessibility-insights

Wondering if the community can help me understand if (scanned) data is only stored in the browser during a 'fast pass' scan? Or does this go to secure hosting elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, Accessibility Insights for Web only stores complete scan data locally in the browser and does not upload results to any sort of external host.

If you chose to allow usage telemetry when you started the extension for the first time, it will upload some anonymous usage data. This includes information about how many violations of each type were found, but it does *not* include any information which would identify the user running the scan or the site the scan was run on - in particular, it does not include the URL or title of the site being scanned, and it does not include the "Path" or "Snippet" fields listed in Fast Pass's Automated Checks results. Telemetry is only sent if you opted in the first time you ran the extension, and you can disable telemetry at any time from the extension's Settings menu.

Though scan data is not stored in a hosted service, Accessibility Insights for Web does have a few features that allow a user to explicitly choose to export certain scan data to a specifically configured external host. You can find more information about that in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62525209), which is related but not quite a duplicate of your question.